# IntelliJ & Maven - mvn command not found

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a drop wizard project created with IntelliJ. 
when I run

```
mvn package
```

I get

```
bash: mvn: command not found
```

I'm on a Mac and I'm following this tutorial: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html

According to IntelliJ documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/maven.html?origin=old_help)

> Maven integration is shipped with IntelliJ IDEA, and you do not need to perform any additional actions to install it. You can start using it straight away for importing Maven projects, working with them and for running Maven goals.

So I don't know what I'm suppose to do in order to use the command line
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You need to add Maven `bin` directory to the PATH.

Comment: npm?  Is that node package manager?  I thought Maven was a Java dependency manager.

Comment: Maven is a Java Build Tool which includes dependency management.

Comment: @Tunaki: how can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In IntelliJ, on the right hand side, click "Maven", and expand "Lifecycle"
Select "Package" and click "Run" (green arrow).

[image]

Comment: that thing is hidden, they should have put it next to the build button

Answer (score 2):

mvn is the command line tool for Maven.
See https://maven.apache.org/install.html for details on how to install it.
Or as you are using a Mac if you use brew try using it to install the maven formula.

Comment: Thanks, I edit my question: according to IntelliJ doc I shouldn't install it manually, if I got it right, so not sure what's wrong

Comment: What is the Homebrew formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you have maven properly installed and you want to configure intelliJ terminal with a custom Terminal or if you want fix "command not found",
follow these steps:

1. Click > File
2. Click > Settings
3. Click > Tools
4. Click > Terminal
5. Edit "Shell path" @ "Application Settings", if you use git bash change current path with:
   **C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe --login**

// The path you may have differs based on your OS, in example: "installationPath\Terminal Folder\bin\sh.exe --login"

6. Click > Apply
7. Click > Ok

I used git bash but technically it should work with every terminal. Do not forget to add --login after the *.exe

If it still doesn't work maybe you need to check:

1. Click > Environment variables
2. Click > System Properties
3. Click > Environment Variables
4. Click > System Variables
5. Select > Path from the list
6. Click > Edit
7. Click > New

Insert the path of your maven bin folder, in example:

- "installationPath\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin"

Also insert the path of your jdk, in example:

- "installationPath\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1"