# MVN command not found on intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to mvn and intellij and I was trying to import a mvn(spring boot) project into intellij but intellij is not able to resolve all the mvn dependencies. And when I type mvn --version on the terminal on intellij it shows mvn command not found.
How do I resolve this issue?
(I have also tried to run mvn install command but that is also not working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ & Maven - mvn command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105004/intellij-maven-mvn-command-not-found)

Comment: here is something which worked for me.....
https://superuser.com/questions/1425976/maven-version-command-is-not-recognized-in-git-bash

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Make sure the Maven is set for the project in IDE: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Maven home directory**. And the internet connection is working for the IDE to download delendencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your internet works. Mark main directory as sources/root by right click on the folder. Build the project completely again.

Also, you can check whether your project consists the mvn settings if not you can configure it to a mvn project and vice versa.

[image: Have a look!]